# Birectional path tracing - connection of paths

Tags: pathtracing, sampling

I have a few questions about setting up a bidirectional path tracer described by Veach [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs348b-03/papers/veach-chapter10.pdf).

I have created both an eye path and a light path. Both are using BRDF for calculating how much light can pass after bounce and directions are sampled with importance sampling.

My first question is: Can I connect all possible combinations of paths? In the example below, it is a connection of points [1;3], [1;4], [1;light], [2;3], [2;4], [2; light]. It is definitely a bad idea to connect the camera with anything, but I am not sure if it the same with directly connecting with a light source.

[image]

And secondly, do I have to average the radiance coming from all the connected paths? I am not implementing a multiple-importance sampling for now. It will be the next step because without it I am adding even more variance.

Last one. Because I am using an importance sampling I am dividing by PDF. But when I am connecting these two paths I am making deterministic connection so I use PDF of 1. Is this right?

Comment: There aren't many resources for BDPT without MIS. I'd suggest reading the original Lafortune's paper on BDPT where he describes one such naive method.

Comment: I suggest directly reading Veach's paper on MIS.

Comment: Lafortune paper?? Never heard of it. I will give it a try.

Comment: But do I have to directly sample the light source??